# Bash script runs fine when run manually, but doesn't fully run from cron

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script to check if a process is running, and if not, to restart it:

```
#!/bin/bash
pidof  Overseer >/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Restarting Overseer:     $(date)" >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/Log.txt
        /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/Overseer >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/BotLog.txt
else
    echo "No action necessary.     $(date)" >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/Log.txt
fi
```

If I open this manually, it starts Overseer fine and I get all the logs perfectly fine.

However, if cron runs this script, Overseer doesn't start and in Log.txt it says it was restarting.
I tried googling and saw suggestions to put the PATH variable into the crontab.

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
* * * * * /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/startOverseer.sh >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/CronLog.txt 2>&1
```

Output in the CronLog.txt file:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Settings'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at lambda_method23(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at Overseer.PteroWS..ctor(String SelectedServer) in C:\Users\ramor\Documents\GitHub\Overseer\Overseer\PteroWS.cs:line 29
   at Overseer.Program..ctor() in C:\Users\ramor\Documents\GitHub\Overseer\Overseer\Program.cs:line 19
   at Overseer.Program.Main() in C:\Users\ramor\Documents\GitHub\Overseer\Overseer\Program.cs:line 14
   at Overseer.Program.<Main>()
/mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/startOverseer.sh: line 8: 31192 Aborted                 /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/Overseer >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/BotLog.txt
```

This error seems related more to the actual program being run though, and is extremely strange since again, this works when run manually.

This is running on a Raspberry Pi 4

Attempted adding the path variable to both the script and the crontab to no effect.

Comment: Could there be some environment variable besides PATH that needs to be defined?

Comment: Honestly i'm not sure. When googling the only answer I could find was PATH which is why i decided to ask

Comment: Consider using process orchestrator, like systemd, that can restart your service.... instead of checking every second for it. `This error seems related more to the actual program being run though` Indeed it is - so consult the program. Could be permissions.

Comment: I don't think I can use systemd for this. It's a c#.NET code I wrote that works fine, I just need a way to automatically restart it if it crashes. I just don't understand why I'm getting an error if cron tries to run it, no files have changed location or anything, but it works perfectly fine otherwise.

Comment: `cron` is a bad and broken non-solution to both permanently running and periodic tasks. I second the above recommendation to use `systemd` to keep processes running, automatically restart them, configure their environment and permissions, track and enforce their dependencies on other system components, manage their logs and other debugging information properly, and … so much more. Reinventing the wheel using a homebrew restarter script run from inherently broken `cron` yields an unreliable solution ar best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the program is looking for an .ini or so. You can try to cd into the script dir before starting.

Example cron:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * cd /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer && startOverseer.sh >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/CronLog.txt 2>&1
```

Edit:
You can cd into scriptdir als in the script itself:

```
pidof  Overseer >/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Restarting Overseer:     $(date)" >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/Log.txt
        cd /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer && Overseer >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/BotLog.txt
else
    echo "No action necessary.     $(date)" >> /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/Log.txt
fi
```

Edit: Some fine tuning:

```
printf -v date '%(%c)T\n' -1  # Actual date and time
LOG_FILE="/mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer/Log.txt"

if ! pidof Overseer &>/dev/null ; then
  echo "Restarting Overseer:     $date" >> "$LOG_FILE"
  cd /mnt/drive/Bots/Overseer && Overseer >> "$LOG_FILE"
else
  echo "No action necessary.     $date" >> "$LOG_FILE"
fi
```

printf eliminates the use of external date command